# Is any attribute got changed when a file or folder is moved(cut & paste) with in same drive in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, timestamp, filesystems, ntfs

Moving(cut & paste) a file or folder in windows within the same drive does not changed its creation or modification time.
Is there a way to determine that the file is new respective to the folder in which it is moved ?
Is there any other attribute that get updated due to move operation?

Comment: The parent folder does not suit? What is the exact scenario do you try to detect?

Comment: On an NTFS file system, moving a file/folder around on the same drive is not actually moving it at all, it is just a rename of the existing item to move a link to it from one parent folder to another. That is why the timestamps do not change, because the item itself does not change.  Move the item to another drive, and it then has to be copied to a new item and the old item deleted.

Comment: Yes @RemyLebeau i tried moving to other drive then timsstamps changed but moving within the same drive does not change timestamps. So is there a way we can determine that the file is being renamed/moved recently.

Comment: @KonstantinL i am trying to detect new files that have been added to some folder or some location based on creation and modification time but  timesatmps does not get changed in case the files/folders are moved within the same drive.

Comment: What is "new" in this context? New after a previous scan? How many files/folders do you need to monitor? What is a "location" that not a folder?

Comment: Also look here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/

Comment: @KonstantinL if a file/folder has been moved to some other folder then i want to determine that that file/folder is new with respect to the folder in which they are moved.